# Separating traditional Chinese character from utf 8 mixture

Tags: c++, c, utf-8

I am writing a program in C/C++ which takes a user's input. The input is a utf-8 string which may mix English with Chinese and some punctuation marks.

My program has to seperate those Chinese characters from the English characters.

As you know, Chinese characters occupy 2 bytes and English characters only 1 byte. I cannot iterate the char array to find if any English characters exist. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You will have to iterate through the char array to find what you want, directly (with your code) or indirectly (with library calls).

Answer (score 0):

Grab ICU4C and use it to iterate by characters.